# Class file's magic value changes during read/write

Tags: java, file-io, binary, .class-file

I'm trying to save java classes into a database. To do so I read files as follows:

```
bytes = com.google.common.io.ByteStreamsByteStreams.toByteArray(url.openStream());
```

Then, those bytes are encoded in base64:

```
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Base64.encodeBytes(bytes);
```

When loading them again, the same thing happens vice versa:

```
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Base64.decode(base64);
```

and its written to a file:

```
com.google.common.io.Files.write(binary, file);
```

However, source and targe files are not identical. Using a binary file viewer shows that they are indeed very similar; just one thing I spotted: The new file begins with

```
EF BF BD EF BF BD EF BF BD EF BF BD
```

instead of the expected

```
CA FE BA BE
```

After that, they're identical for at least a few hundert bytes.

As a logical consequence, I get the following error message when trying to load the class form the new file:

```
java.lang.ClassFormatError: Incompatible magic value 4022320623 in class file ch/unibe/scg/doodle/producerTest/GiantTurtle
```

I have no idea where it breaks, and it's quite hard to debug. My unit tests for file read/write are green. Where could the problem be?

Comment: Well, now you find the place where it goes wrong. It's called debugging, and it's something programmers do **before** they post on stackoverflow. Note: debugging doesn't require that you use an actual debugger, although this can help. You've identified several spots where you transform the data and it's possible that it's getting garbled.

Comment: Note, that the bytes EF BF BD are the UTF-8 encoding for U+FFFD, which is the "replacement character".

Comment: @Kayaman Do you really think I would post here without preceding hours of debugging? First of all, this problem is hard to debug, since data occurs in many different forms, which makes it hard to compare at different states. But I already assured that data doesn't change during program execution.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose Good call, I didn't notice that. But still, that's strange, since I'm only working with bytes...

Comment: Not exactly. Base64 is textual data. What does the data look like before you Base64decode it? It's probably already corrupted in the database.

Comment: Ok, solved it. Due to the special setup needed for Eclipse plugins depending on non-eclipse projects, I forgot one step, so that my code wasn't updated. Thx for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out I had already solved the problem in the code, but not updated the binaries yet: It's an eclipse plugin project, depending on another project for development, but the other project always needs to be built to a jar and copied to the plugin's directory in order to work at runtime.

The problem was that I first had used a String-based `FileWriter`:

```
FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter(file, append);
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
out.write(content);
out.close();
```

Re-packing my project and actually using above code solved the problem.